# Navigate to another view when touchup inside event occurs on UITextfield

Tags: swift, uitableview, viewcontroller

I have already set the identifier for the `segue` from `ViewcontrollerA` to `ViewcontrollerB`. But following code doesn't work:

```
 class ViewcontrollerA: UIViewController {


 @IBOutlet weak var Tasks: UITextField!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }


 @IBAction func move(sender: AnyObject) {

 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("move", sender: sender)

 }

}
```

Is there any way to navigate to the second `ViewController`, when `UITextfield` is "tapped"?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: have you implemented the method- shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: No, I haven't. So, that must be the missing thing?

Comment: will add my answer

Comment: is func move called when textfield is tapped ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri No, it doesn't, but that is what I want.

Comment: implement the textfield delegate didBeginEditing and call the peformSegue there.

Comment: @Walker you want to navigate to second view controller on tap of textfield right????

Comment: @Nirav Yes, right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move on `SecondViewController` on tap of `UITextField` then you can use delegate method `textFieldDidBeginEditing` of `UITextField`like this

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have given the **segue identifier** and **segue kind**

> Replace func move:

```
 @IBAction func move(sender: AnyObject) {

 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("move", sender: self)

 }
```

> Add below code:

```
  override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if identifier == "move" {

            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "move" {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewcontrollerB
            // you can additional work here with navigating VC Object
        }
    }
```

Comment: It says I should replace let vc with "_".

Comment: if you are not using this object to pass any value, then you can skip this method.

Comment: It doesn't work, so I will list, what I've done, so you can correct me. First, I have set a push segue from ViewcontrollerA to ViewcontrollerB with identifier "move".  Second, I have added you're code in my file (just anywhere) and third I have set an IBAction for touchUp inside event for UITextfield, where I have the code as above in my explanation.

Comment: Instead of taking outlet of that move button, perform the segue action on that button itself to ViewControllerB from xib/storyboard and select push. Then no need to add any code..

Comment: But I need to make a UITextField, I know how it works with a button.

Comment: Oh, then let do it in some trickily add that button as textfield overlay so whenever user tap on textfield, the button action will be triggered.